# JS AJAX POST to PHP, edit JSON file is giving errors

Tags: php, json, ajax, post

post function in js:

```
        var srcd = document.getElementById("pictwo").src;

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST", //type of method
          url: "/file.php", //your page
          data: {
            src: srcd
          }, // passing the values
          success: function(res) {
            location.reload(); //do what you want here...

          }

        });
      }
```

file.php:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$src = $_POST["src"];
$jsonString = file_get_contents('jsonFile.json');
$data = json_decode( $jsonString, true );

foreach ( $data as $key => $entry )
{
        if ( $entry['src'] == $src )
        {
                $data[$key]['counter']++;
        }
}
$newJsonString = json_encode( $data );
file_put_contents( 'jsonFile.json', $newJsonString );

?>
```

I know that the `POST` is successful, because I added a `console.log(srcd)` to the js function, and it was the desired value.

jsonFile.json:

```
[
        {
            "src": "https://",
            "counter": "0"
        },
        {
            "src": "https://",
            "counter": "0"
        },
        {
            "src": "https://", 
            "counter": "0"
        },
```

The error in error_logs is :

`PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /file.php on line 8`

After the function is called, the json file is changed to `null`.

Why is this happening?

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: You're JSON is invalid, it has a comma at the end and missing a closing `]`

Comment: @Musa That is an example of the JSON. The real one is valid and 2000 lines long.

Comment: After the `json_decode()` call, try calling `json_last_error_msg()` to see what it gives.